# SSL certificate validations in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, ssl, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, ssl-certificate

How do I validate an SSL certificate from a Windows Phone application? I need to check for criteria like Certificate Issuer Name, Expiry date, Host name match, Certificate chain etc. programmatically from the app. Are these checks handled by the OS itself for trusted certificates? How can I do these validations for self-signed certificates?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to perform complete validation of certificates including OCSP and CRL checks, you can do this using our SecureBlackbox product that works on Windows Phone as well. Free [CryptoBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-cryptobb.php) package is available.

You need to have some set of trusted root and CA certificates to perform validation (you can export them from some desktop browser and carry with your application). As for self-signed certificates - PKI infrastructure is built on the concept of hierarchy of certificates and CAs. Self-signed certificates are not reliable and the only way to validate them is to compare their key and other parameters with some trusted certificate (i.e. each self-signed certificate must be previously known to the application).

Comment: Out of topic but I need to ask a question. I know, in the current Windows Phone platform there is no built-in way to validate ssl certificates without using 3rd party libraries.
I only need to protect my web service from MitM attacks in my Windows Phone 8 app(s). But there are a lot of packages and I'm confused. The question is which EldoS package should I use only to prevent the https connections from MitM.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin If you need an HTTPS or SSL communication, you can use HTTPBlackbox client package, it would be enough.

Answer (score -2):

The details of certificates are saved within browser's database , which needs frequent update from time to time if update is possible.
Security certificates from popular providers such as verisign are easily be detected.

I would recommend to use third party trusted browsers instead of default browser.

Comment: "Use third party trusted browsers" on a Windows Phone? In what universe?

Comment: Hope you are knowing about opera mini, chrome , etc. isnt it .
I stated them as third party browser :)

Comment: None of those browsers are available for this platform.

Comment: I need to check the validations programmatically from the application.

Comment: how can you say that they are not available , i m having windows phone 7.8 that has preinstalled mozilla firefox and opera 9 . @lthibodeaux

Comment: I'd love to know how @Nikhilesh. They are not in development, never have been. Mozilla got as far as a concept stage for a Firefox browser but canned that when it was obvious there was no native SDK and therefore no way to build a browser. If you think you are using Chrome/Firefox on a Windows Phone, you are really using a skinned IE.